# Checkboxes in horizontal form, and on the right side of the label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Is it possible to have the checkbox labels on the left like the others, and the checkbox on the right like the other inputs with a horizontal form?

**My current setup**

[image]

It looks pretty awful.

EDIT:

```
 <%= simple_form_for :apartment, :html => {:multipart => true, :class => 'form-horizontal'}, wrapper: :horizontal_form do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :pets, as: :boolean, label: 'Husdyr tilladt' %>
 <% end %>
```

which generates the following html in the view:

```
 <div class="form-group boolean optional apartment_pets">
   <div class="checkbox"><input value="0" type="hidden" name="apartment[pets]">
     <label class="boolean optional" for="apartment_pets"><input class="boolean optional" type="checkbox" value="1" name="apartment[pets]" id="apartment_pets">
       Husdyr tilladt
     </label>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Could you perhaps add some code? Equally, are you using Bootstrap as your CSS framework?

Comment: @Christian-G I have updated the question with the code now. And your previous suggestion didn't make any difference, unfortunately.

Comment: Updated my answer with your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `pull-right` to the class of your checkbox element like so:

`<input name="uh" id="uhhuh" type="checkbox" class="pull-right" />`

**Updated answer with user provided code:**

```
  <div class="form-group boolean optional apartment_pets">
    <div class="checkbox"><input value="0" type="hidden" name="apartment[pets]">
      <label class="boolean optional" for="apartment_pets">Husdyr tilladt</label>
        <input class="boolean optional" type="checkbox" value="1" name="apartment[pets]" id="apartment_pets" class="pull-right">        
    </div>
  </div>
```

I never used `simple_form` but from browsing the documentation, it looks like you should use a combination of `:label => false` and `:inline_label => true` to position your label.